# "increment" character in javascript according to en_US collation sort order

Tags: javascript, collation

I want to get the next en_US collation character given a character. So inputting `"a"` I would get `"b"`.  I can handle this manually for a-z 0-9, but I'm not exactly sure how I would go about getting the special characters right.  They have a specific ordering, I would guess, and I need to get the one that comes next in order.

In case you are wondering the reason, I need to do a range search in mongodb using collations.  In order to find the end of the range, I need to "increment" the last character by 1.

I have taken a look at this page http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=en_US&SHOWCollationElements=1#CollationElements but I'm not exactly sure how to decipher it.

Comment: You can try using ASCII. Convert your character to ASCII & then increment the value by 1 & again convert back to user readable format. Not sure will this help or not.

Comment: Yeah, I seem to get good enough results using `String.fromCharCode(lastChar.charCodeAt(0) + 1);` as well.  But I'm wondering if anybody knows the real way to get official en_us results.